# Centos 7, root is almost full, already try du -shx and lsof | grep deleted but still can't find the culprits

Tags: disk-space-utilization, centos7

We are using centos 7 and have 50G allocated for root.  We are running out of spaces as df reported that 45G (90%) is used. But when I try to find what's been eating the space, du only shows less than 10G is being used. I also try looking for large deleted file with lsof (as another solved thread suggested) but still nothing. Here are the outputs of df, du and lsof command. Pls advice on what should I do next.

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   45G  5,3G  90% /
devtmpfs                 1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1,9G  103M  1,8G   6% /run
tmpfs                    1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home  412G  5,6G  406G   2% /home
/dev/sda1                497M  158M  339M  32% /boot
tmpfs                    1,9G  103M  1,8G   6% /var/named/chroot/run/named

du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
du: cannot access ‘proc/10910/task/10910/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/10910/task/10910/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/10910/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/10910/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
5,6G    home
1,7G    usr
542M    var
133M    boot
103M    run
26M etc
19M root
12K tmp
0   sys
0   srv

lsof | grep "deleted"
tuned       749         root    6u      REG              253,1      4096     196293 /tmp/ffiX1PEcV (deleted)
gmain       749  908    root    6u      REG              253,1      4096     196293 /tmp/ffiX1PEcV (deleted)
tuned       749  909    root    6u      REG              253,1      4096     196293 /tmp/ffiX1PEcV (deleted)
tuned       749  910    root    6u      REG              253,1      4096     196293 /tmp/ffiX1PEcV (deleted)
tuned       749  911    root    6u      REG              253,1      4096     196293 /tmp/ffiX1PEcV (deleted)
```

Comment: Is it possible you have something mounted over a directory that used to exist?  Like, if you used to have a `/home` then mounted another directory over it, then all the space used by the old `/home` would be used still, but inaccessible

Comment: maybe so, how do i check them? thx

Comment: Sadly, the only way I can think of would be to unmount what's there and see if there was something "under" it.  That could be disruptive though if there are people trying to use `/home` which strikes me as the most likely culprit

Comment: You can use `mount --bind / /other-root-view` to remount part of a filesystem someplace else (makes it accessible in two places, submounts aren't included).

Comment: Also try running `du` without the `*` argument. If there is a hidden directory or file in your root then bash expansion won't include those when expanding `*`

Comment: It seems that a process lock some space. I had this issue deleting mysql home directory and let the server process running. Check your running process.

Comment: @Brian CMIIW, mount --bind to some other path will grant me additional space, right ? Well, that certainly will solve one thing, but still I'm curious about the root of the problem. What's been eating up my disk space?

Comment: @Eric   your suggestion to unmount is tempting. But as you says, it can be disruptive and it's in fact a production server. Still finding the right time to execute it.

Comment: No it won't get you any more space. It will let you take a look to see what is in the directories that are mounted over (and thus hidden). As well the utility `ncdu` is useful for exploring where space is being used on a directory basis (vs mount point).

Comment: @brian, so after mount --bind, next I should compare the two places?

Comment: Read the first comment. Remounting someplace else without submounts lets you peak underneath those directories. So look in /other-root-view (or whatever directory you remounted to) and check the home subdirectory and any other directory mounted over to see if they contain files etc.